# Element Iteration in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to make a web scraper that scrapes the New York Times search results page and scrapes and stores things like publication date, author, title, etc. Every other field like title and date are correctly scraped and stored but not the Author because some articles don't have the author element.

What I'm trying to do is to iterate through the search results and store the authors name, if the name is not found i want to set it to -1. I have this code but it's not storing -1 in the missing author's place.

(I'm just starting in web scraping and this is my first project.)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
authors = []

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.nytimes.com/search?dropmab=false&query=Machine%20Learning&sort=newest')

for i in range(6):
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//button[contains(.,"Show More")])').click()

result_cards = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li.css-1l4w6pd')

for item in result_cards:
    try:
        author = item.find_elements_by_xpath('(//p[@class="css-15w69y9"])')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("No author found for this")
        author = -1
for auth in author:
    authors.append(auth.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last `for` loop you're iterating over `author` which will raise an error because it is not iterable.

you can omit the last for loop.

I've made some changes in your try-except statements which should do your Job.

```
for item in result_cards:
    try:
        author = item.find_elements_by_xpath('(//p[@class="css-15w69y9"])')
        authors.append(author)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("No author found for this")
        authors.append(-1)
```

The above code will append the **author** to the `authors` list, if the author is found otherwise it will append `-1`  in your list.

Comment: Hey, I think your code is doing the work but  `authors` is a list of FirefoxWebElements like `authors = [[FirefoxWebElement, FirefoxWebElement, FirefoxWebElement...` I tried to extract the text from it but failed.

Comment: I think you mean `item.find_elements_by_xpath('(//p[@class="css-15w69y9"])')` returns a `list`. If this is the case then you should be able to filter it out using index on the `authors` list.

Comment: I was able to filter the text from that list but to my surprise, there are no -1 values. The scraper selected 60 results with 6 missing author name, but the list only returned 54 names. No -1 where the author was not found.

Comment: check the length of the `authors`, if the final length of the list `authors` is 60 then it must contain -1 otherwise this means there are no missing author names.